# Is it possible to change ITAB during aRFC parallel processing using TABLES parameter?

Tags: parallel-processing, abap

I'm currently designing parallel processing (by using aRFC), for mass GI job.

The problem is - How can i get return of EACH job result?

I used TABLES parameter, which are declared in main report (gt_result), and when aRFC is done, each FM doing MODIFY itab inside the function.

The problem is - inside each job, I checked data is changed(inside the gt_result), but when job is finished, and return to main report program, ITAB wasn't changed!

Is it possible to change ITAB value, using aRFC parallel processing? or Is it other way to get result from each job?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit : Here is a code snippet

Main Report :

```
DATA: g_task(20) TYPE n VALUE '100',  "Task name administration
      g_progs    TYPE i,              "Number of task in progress
      g_sprog    TYPE i,              "Number of task started
      g_eprog    TYPE i,              "Number of task finished
      pa_wpnum   TYPE int4 VALUE 5,
      jobs       TYPE int4 VALUE 100. "Number of task to be proceeded

TYPES : BEGIN OF gs_target,
          matnr TYPE matnr_d,
          cnt   TYPE i,
        END OF gs_target.

DATA : gt_target TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF gs_target,
       wa_target TYPE gs_target.

DATA : gt_6040_para TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zspp6040_para,
       wa_6040_para TYPE zspp6040_para.

DATA : lv_cnt_seqno TYPE i,
       lv_flag      TYPE c.

DATA : gt_para_test TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zpara_test,
       wa_para_test TYPE zpara_test.

DATA : gv_fs_name(10) TYPE c.

** Test Data Append **

wa_target-matnr = 'A'.
wa_target-cnt = 300.

APPEND wa_target TO gt_target.

wa_target-matnr = 'B'.
wa_target-cnt = 657.

APPEND wa_target TO gt_target.

wa_target-matnr = 'C'.
wa_target-cnt = 1231.

APPEND wa_target TO gt_target.

wa_target-matnr = 'D'.
wa_target-cnt = 831.

APPEND wa_target TO gt_target.

wa_target-matnr = 'E'.
wa_target-cnt = 918.

APPEND wa_target TO gt_target.

** Test Data Append END **


** Split target into 1:300 ratio - for later use?

LOOP AT gt_target INTO wa_target.

  DO.
    lv_cnt_seqno = 1.

    wa_target-cnt = wa_target-cnt - 300.

    wa_6040_para-matnr = wa_target-matnr.
    wa_6040_para-seqno = lv_cnt_seqno.

    APPEND wa_6040_para TO gt_6040_para.

    IF wa_target-cnt > 0.
      lv_cnt_seqno = lv_cnt_seqno + 1.
    ELSEIF wa_target-cnt <= 0.
      CLEAR lv_cnt_seqno.
      lv_flag = 'X'.
    ENDIF.

    IF lv_flag = 'X'.
      CLEAR : lv_flag.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.
  CLEAR : wa_6040_para.
ENDLOOP.

CLEAR : lv_flag.

** End Spliting Part **

** Making 'Data' Part - In real use, it should be the 'item' part of looping BAPI,
** Which are used for making GI document, containing 300 items.

LOOP AT gt_target INTO wa_target.
  lv_cnt_seqno = 1.
  DO.
    wa_para_test-seqno = lv_cnt_seqno.
    wa_para_test-matnr = wa_target-matnr.

    APPEND wa_para_test TO gt_para_test.

    lv_cnt_seqno = lv_cnt_seqno + 1.

    IF lv_cnt_seqno = wa_target-cnt.

      wa_para_test-seqno = lv_cnt_seqno.
      wa_para_test-matnr = wa_target-matnr.

      APPEND wa_para_test TO gt_para_test.

      lv_flag = 'X'.
    ENDIF.

    IF lv_flag = 'X'.
      CLEAR : lv_flag.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDDO.
ENDLOOP.

** End of 'Data Making' Part.

** aRFC part, sending job for 'Matnr', looping 300 items AND changing gt_6040_para, which are used for checking Success, or Error.

LOOP AT gt_target INTO wa_target.
  WAIT UNTIL g_progs LE pa_wpnum.

  ADD 1 TO g_progs.

  CALL FUNCTION 'Z_PP_PARA_TEST'
    STARTING NEW TASK g_task DESTINATION IN GROUP DEFAULT
    PERFORMING return_z_pp_para_test ON END OF TASK
    EXPORTING
      lv_matnr        = wa_target-matnr
    TABLES
      zpara_target    = gt_para_test
      ztpp6040_change = gt_6040_para.


  ADD 1 TO g_task.
  ADD 1 TO g_sprog.

ENDLOOP.

** End of aRFC part.

WAIT UNTIL g_sprog <= g_eprog.

LOOP AT gt_6040_para INTO wa_6040_para.
  WRITE : wa_6040_para-matnr, wa_6040_para-seqno, wa_6040_para-msgtx, wa_6040_para-msgty.
ENDLOOP.
```

aRFC Function Part :

```
FUNCTION z_pp_para_test.

  DATA : lv_cnt TYPE int4.
  DATA : lv_concat_data(10) TYPE c.
  DATA : lv_index TYPE int4.

  LOOP AT zpara_target WHERE matnr = lv_matnr.
    lv_cnt = lv_cnt + 1.

    zpara_target-msgtx = sy-tabix.
    MODIFY zpara_target.

    IF lv_cnt = 300.
      lv_index = lv_index + 1.
      READ TABLE ZTPP6040_CHANGE WITH KEY matnr = zpara_target-matnr
                                        seqno = lv_index.

      IF sy-subrc = 0.
        ZTPP6040_CHANGE-msgty = 'S'.
        ZTPP6040_CHANGE-msgtx = lv_index.

        MODIFY ZTPP6040_CHANGE index sy-index.
      ENDIF.
      lv_cnt = 0.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.

ENDFUNCTION.
```

Returning Part

```
FORM return_z_pp_para_test USING taskname.

  RECEIVE RESULTS FROM FUNCTION 'Z_PP_PARA_TEST'.

  SUBTRACT 1 FROM g_progs.

  ADD 1 TO g_eprog.

ENDFORM.
```

ZSPP6040_PARA Structure

```
MATNR MATNR_D
SEQNO INT4
MSGTX BAPI_MTYPE
MSGTY BAPI_MSG
```

ZPARA_TEST Structure

```
MATNR MATNR_D
SEQNO INT4
MSGTX BAPI_MTYPE
```

Comment: Sure it's possible. Probably you don't use Asynchronous RFC correctly. To get the asynchronous results in the waiting subroutine or method, use `RECEIVE RESULTS FROM ...` Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks, Sandra - I'll add some code snippet which I've wrote.

Comment: GI = Goods Issue? I suppose your aRFC FM is a mock data, can you describe what it is doing?

Comment: Yup, It based on mock data.
I'm just testing how it can works - I need to make the 'returning part'
In real world situation - I'll substitute the FM part with real BAPI ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `RECEIVE RESULTS FROM FUNCTION` instruction](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapreceive.htm) requires that you state which parameters you would like to receive and where you would like to store the results. Unfortunately all the parameters are optional, and those you don't explicitly mention just get discarded. So calling it with *no* parameters (like you do here) is pointless but still legal.

You likely declared the table you pass to the aRFC call as a global variable (don't do that!) and then in your `FORM return_z_pp_para_test` you again access that global table which wasn't changed yet.

In order to receive the actual results of the function-call, do this:

```
DATA: lt_results_target TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF gs_target,
      lt_results_6040 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zspp6040_para.

RECEIVE RESULTS FROM FUNCTION 'Z_PP_PARA_TEST'
   TABLES
       zpara_target    = lt_results_target
       ztpp6040_change = lt_results_6040.
```

Now the **local** tables `lt_results_target` and `lt_results_6040` should contain a copy of the data after it was changed by that asynchronous function-call.

Comment: Thanks! I think It's working - Modifying global variable using returning local variable.